# Does there exist a set $X$ for every set $Y$, such that $X \subseteq Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This would be true for setting $X$ to be the empty set since the empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: Yes that works, despite your title being slightly ambiguous between "there is a set $X$ such that $X$ is a subset of every set $Y$" and "for every set $Y$ there is a set $X$ such that $X$ is a subset of that $Y$"

Comment: Absolutely correct, but I don't follow why "every set is a subset of itself" is relevant. It's true, of course, but I don't think you need this observation to complete your proof.

Comment: We might note that the axiom of regularity ensures that $\varnothing$ is unique with this property.